# How can i verify (through an algorithm) if the gps coordinates are in decimal or in degreees ?

Tags: algorithm, gps, functional-programming

I can verify the difference, but i need a simple code to verify if an coordinate is in degree or in decimal.

Comment: In "decimal", what do you mean ???

Comment: Your question does not make sense: Did you mean "in degrees, minutes seconds (47° 11 ' 12") " or in "decimal degrees (47.1234)" ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to tell a degree/minutes/seconds from a degrees/fraction-of-degrees representation, with no other clue (no separator), the answer is easy: you can't.

For instance, assume 3 positions for the integer part and 4 position for the non-integer part, `1002233` can be read as both `100°22'33"` or `100.2233°`.

Just like `3/7` can be `March 7` or `3 juillet`.